# Stuck with while loop

Tags: bash, while-loop

I have a tmp directory with some files in it. I need to parse these file names and then proceed to parse the contents of each one.

```
!/bin/bash

TMPDIR=/home/david/tmp
     ip_targets(){
        while IFS= read -r file_name; do
            echo "This is: $file_name"
                while IFS= read -r ip;do
                        echo "This is IP: $ip"
                done < <(cat "$file_name")  ## Is this wrong ?
        done < <(find "$TMPDIR" -regex '.*.vms$')
     }
     ip_targets
```

How can I achieve this ? The above allows $file_name to be echoed but not the contents of it.

Comment: why are you doing `< <(cat "file_name")` instead of just  `< "$file_name"` ?

Comment: @ymonad - `< "$file_name"` does not work nor does  `< <(cat "file_name")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
!/bin/bash

TMPDIR=/home/david/tmp
     ip_targets(){
        while IFS= read -r file_name; do
            echo "This is: $file_name"
            grep -woE "\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b" $file_name    
        done < <(find "$TMPDIR" -regex '.*.vms$')
     }
     ip_targets
```

Comment: this does not work no errors given but the grep does nothing.

Comment: Please post a sample vms file so I can test it for you